# How to get results using yelp api

Tags: php, api, yelp

Sorry, this might be pretty basic.  I'm trying to use the Yelp API and am running a test search for McDonalds in Baltimore.

this is the code:

```
<?php

    $AccountKey = "XXXX";
    $restaurant = "McDonalds";
    $city = "Baltimore";

    $file = "test.txt";

    $data = http_get("http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?term=".$restaurant."&location=".$city."&ywsid=".$AccountKey);

    file_put_contents($file, $data);

 ?>
```

I'm trying to store the results in test.txt which I can then parse but its not working.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "but its not working"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you didn't open the text file.

```
// Open the file to get existing content
$data = file_get_contents($file);
$data. = http_get("http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?term=".$restaurant."&location=".$city."&ywsid=".$AccountKey);
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

[more details](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)